# get data with ajax & jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a problem with my ajax call on my website.

I would like to dynamically load my pages from a database with jquery and ajax object.

But they don't return, and I don't know if the problem comes from php or my jquery script.

Here is my table:

- id(int, PK, AI)
- label (char)
- title (char)
- content (char)

Here is my php script (get_page.php):

```
    <?php
try
{
    $bdd = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=wemusic;charset=utf8', 'root', 'root');
}
catch(Exception $e)
{
        die('Erreur : '.$e->getMessage());
}
$reponse = $bdd->prepare('SELECT title, content FROM page WHERE label = ?');
$reponse->execute(array($_GET['label']));
$data = $reponse->fetch();

echo $data;
?>
```

My first question is: does `echo` work with an array? Or should I use echo json_encode?

And there is my jquery script :

```
    $("document").ready(function(){
    var bloc = $(".third").hide();
    var trigger = $(".presta-link");
        trigger.click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            page = $(this).data('page');
            $.ajax({
                    url: 'get_page.php',
                    type: 'get',
                    data: {label: page},
                    success: function (data) {
                        bloc.show();
                        $(".presta-title").empty().html(data.title);
                        $(".presta-description").empty().html(data.content);
                    },
                    error:function(jqXHR)
                    {
                        console.log(jqXHR);
                    }
                });
        });
});
```

Also: jquery is loaded, and my links all have a `data-page` value.

But I don't get any response. No php error, no jqXHR message.

Comment: To answer the question about the echo, it doesn't work with arrays (throw a notice, array to string conversion). For the main problem, see @Barmar's answer

Answer (score 0):

Your `success` function is expecting a JSON response, but you're not echoing JSON in the PHP script. Change

```
echo $data;
```

to:

```
echo json_encode($data);
```

And in your `$.ajax` call, add:

```
dataType: 'json',
```

By the way, you don't have to call `.empty()` before `.html()`, since `.html()` completely replaces the contents of the element (in fact, the first thing it does internally is call `.empty()`).

Comment: Founded the answer 2minutes after asking question , but thank you very much.
I had a problem too with my sql request. (escape field's name !)